# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

As you can see, the [new design](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/design-for-ux-se) is now live. Thank you for your feedback. We have also updated the new look to UX.se's [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/stackux) account and its [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/user-experience). I hope the new design will help to attract new UX professionals to the site. Of course, ultimately what matters is the awesome content you all have been creating. Thank you for being a great community!

I'd also like to thank [Dmitry](http://www.usabilitypost.com/) for his great design. If you're interested, he just posted a blog entry on the [design process](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/) of the site.

If you see any CSS/Usability related bugs in the new design, please let me know. Start a new post please, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug."

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow two URLs in your browser and do a hard refresh:

http://sstatic.net/ux/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/uxmeta/img/favicon.ico

Once the site stats improve some, I'll remove the "Beta" tag from the logo and make the site official!

Comment: I know I'm not a member here but I wanted to say that to me, the site looks FANTASTIC - clean, well proportioned, great color balance.

Comment: Great job Jin! Some of the stack sites feel lacking in UI focus, but this one is pretty well-balanced.

Answer (score 2):

Its definetely professional looking.  Something is missing though...something for the designer in us.  A twist, some charm...something "different".  Something with more unique personality.  I know the hard work that went into the design and appreciate it.  I just want to be honest with feedback.  It feels a little conservative to me.

Comment: What's with the downvoting everyone? Constructive criticism is a bad thing now? The fact that you can't quite pinpoint the problem doesn't make it any less constructive, it just shows that we're dealing with design, which is vague and subjective by nature. Downvoting is for answers which are inherently wrong, or not useful. Not for those you happen to disagree with. And @Jin specifically asked for feedback. Gees. +1 just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Vitaly: On many SE Meta sites downvoting doesn't mean "this question or answer is not useful", but just "I disagree". For this reason reputation on meta does not come from meta activity but from activity on the main site. So the downvoters probably just disagree that something is missing from the site.

Comment: @Jan I weren't aware of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this star, moved into the 'x' before. Can somebody tell me where? Is it a meaningful citation? My first impression was 'U*X + Star(s and stripes) => USA'. Later I realised the star has the same shape as the star, used to mark favourites.

Comment: I fear your question here in answer form will not get an answer. Better open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your best work yet, Jin! I've always been a staunch critic :), but I'm happy to report I was immediately drawn in by the UX site design. Thank you!

There's only one thing that slightly bothers me and that is the balance of the UX logo. I can't pinpoint it either, but I think a clear "ux" flowing into each other would have a stronger character, albeit more generic, than the star that seems to strong-arm the X out of the way. Consider adding a third, dark color to fill in the cut-out parts of the U and X.

Comment: thanks. But I didn't design it this time. It was done by Dmitry. He's written a blog post about his design process: http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/