# Has the change to the non-beta theme improved traffic to the site?

Tags: discussion, design, site-growth

One of the reasons stated for giving the site it's public theme early was to help increase the traffic to the site.

See the [question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/new-design-launched) where Jin introduced the design.

Has there been an improvement and is the site any nearer to leaving beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been a huge improvement but it's hard to say whether it was due to the design, as the analytics we have only started on April 1st and Jin introduced the new design on April 22nd.

However, the average number of daily visitors has grown since then from **around 1000** to **around 1600**, with a huge uptick in the past 3 weeks.

Are we closer to leaving beta? I think so, but it's not something I've heard being discussed lately - I'm sure Robert and Jin have talked about it internally though.