# Any news on when (or indeed if) we're going graduate to full site status?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-growth

Following up from [my previous question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/444/has-the-change-to-the-non-beta-theme-improved-traffic-to-the-site) on this subject, I was wondering what our status was.

We've had the public theme for a few months now, so have the site's stats improved enough for a full launch and the removal of "beta" from the site logo?

Comment: I know I'll lose access to the tools menu (being only half way to 10K) but it's a price I'm willing to pay and it'll spur me on to earn the necessary reputation to regain access.

Comment: status-complete :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official response from Rebecca Chernoff is **they're waiting for participation to reach a tipping point**. So be thinking about how we can promote the site and how the UX of the [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-experience) can be improved to communicate what really matters.

**Update**: The SciFi site just launched, putting to rest any doubt about whether the stats on the Area 51 page have anything to do with when (or indeed if) we'll graduate.

```
UX    2.9k questions 11.0k answers 99% answered 8.6k users 2.1k visits/day
SciFi 1.8k questions  3.9k answers 96% answered 3.4k users 1.6k visits/day
```

Comment: Wait, what about the Area 51 page? I figured everything but the stats there was set in stone once we're in beta.

Comment: I mean we should suggest changes to the design of that page. It's misleading, because apparently the stats and labels don't correlate with the actual criteria SE uses to determine when a site should launch.

Comment: I misread your question, I thought you meant edit the Area 51 page for UX, not the UX of Area 51's page style. I certainly agree their criteria need to be clearer. If our question volume isn't enough to launch then it's not "okay," and if they're waiting for more visits per day then our count certainly isn't "excellent"

Comment: @ edit, sci fi stats: LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAME

Answer (score 4):

Jin mentioned in chat two weeks ago that yes, we'll be graduated from beta soon. I'm curious what "soon" means, but I'm sure the team knows what they're doing ;)

FWIW, we're currently doing around 5000 page views (1.6k visits) a day, with a recent spike to 9k during the week of that rotating cube question. We're also averaging 20 new users a day, with 50 during the spike. We get about 10 new questions a day accompanied by 30 answers.

Comment: Thanks for the stats. I'll mention this to the community team next time I bump into one of them in chat.

Comment: It's often about timing. They just had community elections for three sites (afaik, since mine was one of them) and they're still wrapping things up with that. Most likely once all this kerfluffle has died down, you guys are in the next batch.