# When can we elect moderators?

Tags: feature-request, moderators

This site has now been in beta for [441 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-experience). We've exceeded by far all of the target metrics required for launch (except questions per day -- but our questions tend to be more engaging and most are interesting to a wide swath of the community). I don't want to keep [beating a dead pony](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/any-news-on-when-or-indeed-if-were-going-graduate-to-full-site-status).

Instead, what I'd like to know, is whether it would be possible to go ahead and have elections? I was appointed as a moderator *pro tempore* based on a week of activity,  well over a year ago now -- longer than the term of *elected* moderators. There are now plenty of people qualified to do the job, and the community is well established.

If Stack Exchange can't commit to a launch date, can we at least have elections? Or is it true that Joel Spolsky hates democracy? Pretty please. Think of the children.

Comment: Ponies don't die, they just evolve into unicorns.

Comment: Okay then, I don't want to keep beating a live unicorn.

Comment: Better not, or they'll kick your teeth in. With rainbows.

Answer (score 2):

Moderator elections happen after graduation and even though we got a "proper" theme early I can't see that changing. <strike>We need to get that sorted first.</strike>

Now that we've graduated moderator elections should be on the agenda sometime soon.

Also once elected, the job's yours for as long as you want it.

*(And don't worry I won't stand :).)*