# Vote to close options should include GD.SE and SO

Tags: feature-request

You know, this thing:
[image]

The most common sites we migrate to are easily Graphic Design.stackexchange and Stack Overflow; could we get these included in the Off Topic options? Usually this is a result of asking implementation questions in code or design, or asking a purely stylistic question. If anything I bet we migrate to those 10x as often as we migrate to meta.ux.

Update: I investigated the actual numbers from our migrations; we moved 9 questions from UX to  Meta UX, **17 from UX to Graphic Design**, and **31 from UX to Stack Overflow**. So okay, only 5x as many questions are migrated to SO and GD as opposed to Meta UX, but that's still pretty significant.

In addition more questions probably would have been migrated rather than closed were people able to use a close vote to indicate where the questions should go (currently the only way to migrate suggest migrating these is to flag moderators directly). Other than MetaUX, GD and SO only SuperUser had more than ~5 questions, SU might have had 10.

Update: Now that we've launched we should seriously discuss this and what additional options may be appropriate, as we can actually get this changed now.

Comment: GREAT suggestion! This would make it so much easier to do community moderation effectively.

Comment: Totally agreed.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 3):

To get these added we need to show evidence of need.

I don't have the time right now, but if someone could go through the [recently migrated](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) questions and [recently closed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last14days) lists to see which ones have gone/should have gone to each of these sites and list them.

If there's enough the team should be willing to add them.

However, bear in mind we're still in beta and that migration paths won't be added until we [graduate](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/any-news-on-when-or-indeed-if-were-going-graduate-to-full-site-status).

Comment: I counted the recently migrated, added the totals to my question.  31 to SO, only 9 to meta UX. less than 5 of most of the other, maybe 10 SuperUsers.

Comment: There's so much overlap between UX and GD that I think both sites should have each other's sites on on the 'belongs on other site' option.