# Who made the webdesign of User Experience?

Tags: support, design

My impression about the webdesign of [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) is brilliant. The header section with the great logo and the intense blue background meeting the beige `Ask Question` button. The design of tags all over the page. And the very clean icons for upvoting, downvoting and accepting answers.

Who crafted this design? And is there there is additional work from this person for inspiration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm sure you're aware, UX.StackExchange is just one of may sites in the [StackExchange network](https://stackexchange.com/). Most of the features here are present on all sites around the network (tags, voting arrows etc).

This *particular* site was developed by [Dmitry Fadeyev](http://www.usabilitypost.com/) in combination with the resident StackExchange designer [Jin Yang](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/). Dimitry wrote a post about the design [on his website](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/)

There are some other articles in this very meta site about this design process:

- [Design for UX.SE](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/design-for-ux-se)
- [New Design Launched](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/new-design-launched)

You can probably find out more about the general design from the main StackExchange blog site. Here is a post to get you started, which discusses how the theme for the current Beta sites was chosen:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/

Comment: Thanks, my question was specially about the User Experience site as you assumed.