# What's the story behind the star theme?

Tags: discussion, design

I find the site's theme to be pleasing to the eye.

However, just out of curiosity, what's up with the star theme? Where did that come from?

There's a star embedded in the "UX" logo, and the badges have stars in them as well. *What does it all mean???*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you're in luck. A [blog post about the design of UX Stack Exchange](http://usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/) was published by the designer Dmitry Fadeyev when it went live. Here's what he had to say about the star:

> One of the more difficult parts of the design was the logo. I wanted to add some sort of symbolism to show what UX is about. I didn’t want to focus on the tools, but rather the goal. The final logo is a combination of the two letters “UX” with a star in the middle created using negative space. The star signifies excellence, which is what the field of UX strives to achieve in product design.

There are also some other posts on this meta site about the design of this site, probably the most useful being this one: [Design for UX.SE](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/design-for-ux-se). Have a look at the Related question in the sidebar against that question for more linked posts about it.